# How to concatenate multiple images to send them to Firebase Storage as one file

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am working on a canvas to video converter. Frames are generated from an animated canvas with `.toDataURL()`, then sent to a Cloud Function to be converted into a video file with FFMPEG. Since the http requests have their limits, instead of sending them directly in a request body, I am first uploading frames to Firebase Storage, then downloading them in my Cloud Function. With FPS set to 25 and a 1 minute video duration I get 1.5K frames that need to be sent to Firebase Storage. Their free daily limit is 20K uploads which I can hit pretty fast if I have a longer video or multiple canvas conversions each day. My idea was to concatenated those Data URLs in a single text file, upload it to Firebase Storage, then split into individual files in my Cloud Function.

```
const frames = [];

for (let index = 0; index < maxFrames; index++) {
  ...
  frames.push(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', .75));
}

const blob = new Blob([frames.join('\n')], { type: 'text/plain' });
```

Everything works like a charm with short videos, however longer videos get this `Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length` error which basically means that the resulting string is too long. Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: I've checked their Blazing plan options and uploading limits can be lifted pretty cheap. However, I'd still love to know if anybody can come up with something better.

Comment: What about simply batching them into smaller chunks? So instead of one 20s "video" that exceeds the limits, split it into smaller 5s chunks. Depending on what encoding formats you are using, you could then have 4 workers processing the 5s chunks and then one more that assembles it when the pieces are completed.

Comment: @samthecodingman, looks like this is the way to go about it. Thanks!